# 'FillPoly' Psychtoolbox draws shapes only on one side of the screen

Tags: psychtoolbox

I'm trying to draw triangles in Psychtoolbox using the 'FillPoly'. The triangles vary in number from trial to trial, with min. 3 and max. 10 triangles on the screen. The triangles are evenly spaced around an imaginary circle.
Up to 6 objects per trial, the triangles are drawn fine. 
Starting from 7 objects on the screen, no more triangles get drawn on the left side of the screen. On the right side of the screen, they work fine.

Has anyone an idea what could cause the problem? Thank you in advance!

3 relevant bits from the code:
first, the coordinates for the items are set

```
   angles(1) = 270;% the position of the first item
   %setSize(i) = number of items on screen for trial i

   step = 360/setSize(i);%other items are positioned in relation to the first

   for u = 2:setSize(i),
    angles(u) = angles(u-1) + step;    % defining the circle points by the          angles (first point is already fixed by first angle)
end


% for the triangles
anglesDegtri = linspace(0, 360, 3 + 1);
anglesRadtri = anglesDegtri * (pi / 180);
for j = 1:(setSize(i))
    Xvalue = cosd(angles(j))*expinfo.radius + expinfo.x;    % coordinate of the center of the object on the screen
    Yvalue = sind(angles(j))*expinfo.radius + expinfo.y;
    circlevalue(j, 1) = Xvalue- expinfo.radi;            % defining the points on the axes for each circle (adding and subtracting the radius to get 4 points per circle)
    circlevalue(j, 2) = Yvalue- expinfo.radi;
    circlevalue(j, 3) = Xvalue+ expinfo.radi;
    circlevalue(j, 4) = Yvalue+ expinfo.radi;


    xx(j) = (circlevalue(j,1)+circlevalue(j,3))/2; %x of each item in set size
    yy(j) = (circlevalue(j,2)+circlevalue(j,4))/2; %y of each item in set size

end
xx = xx(1,:);
yy = yy(1,:);
```

I precalculate triangles' coordinates. "set size" is the amount of stimuli on-screen on a given trial, and may change between 3 and 10

```
%precalculating vectors for all possible triangle positions
    if setSize(i) == 3
        triyPosVector1 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(1);
        trixPosVector1 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(1);
        triyPosVector2 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(2);
        trixPosVector2 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(2);
        triyPosVector3 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(3);
        trixPosVector3 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(3);
        triyPosVector = [triyPosVector1; triyPosVector2; triyPosVector3];
        trixPosVector = [trixPosVector1; trixPosVector2; trixPosVector3];
    elseif setSize(i) == 4
        triyPosVector1 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(1);
        trixPosVector1 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(1);
        triyPosVector2 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(2);
        trixPosVector2 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(2);
        triyPosVector3 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(3);
        trixPosVector3 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(3);
        triyPosVector4 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(4);
        trixPosVector4 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(4);
        triyPosVector = [triyPosVector1; triyPosVector2; triyPosVector3; triyPosVector4];
        trixPosVector = [trixPosVector1; trixPosVector2; trixPosVector3; trixPosVector4];
    elseif setSize(i) == 5
        triyPosVector1 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(1);
        trixPosVector1 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(1);
        triyPosVector2 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(2);
        trixPosVector2 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(2);
        triyPosVector3 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(3);
        trixPosVector3 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(3);
        triyPosVector4 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(4);
        trixPosVector4 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(4);
        triyPosVector5 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(5);
        trixPosVector5 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(5);
        triyPosVector = [triyPosVector1; triyPosVector2; triyPosVector3; triyPosVector4; triyPosVector5];
        trixPosVector = [trixPosVector1; trixPosVector2; trixPosVector3; trixPosVector4; trixPosVector5];
    elseif setSize(i) == 6
        triyPosVector1 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(1);
        trixPosVector1 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(1);
        triyPosVector2 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(2);
        trixPosVector2 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(2);
        triyPosVector3 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(3);
        trixPosVector3 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(3);
        triyPosVector4 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(4);
        trixPosVector4 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(4);
        triyPosVector5 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(5);
        trixPosVector5 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(5);
        triyPosVector6 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(6);
        trixPosVector6 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(6);
        triyPosVector = [triyPosVector1; triyPosVector2; triyPosVector3; triyPosVector4; triyPosVector5; triyPosVector6];
        trixPosVector = [trixPosVector1; trixPosVector2; trixPosVector3; trixPosVector4; trixPosVector5; trixPosVector6];
    elseif setSize(i) == 7
        triyPosVector1 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(1);
        trixPosVector1 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(1);
        triyPosVector2 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(2);
        trixPosVector2 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(2);
        triyPosVector3 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(3);
        trixPosVector3 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(3);
        triyPosVector4 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(4);
        trixPosVector4 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(4);
        triyPosVector5 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(5);
        trixPosVector5 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(5);
        triyPosVector6 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(6);
        trixPosVector6 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(6);
        triyPosVector7 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(7);
        trixPosVector7 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(7);
        triyPosVector = [triyPosVector1; triyPosVector2; triyPosVector3; triyPosVector4; triyPosVector5; triyPosVector6; triyPosVector7];
        trixPosVector = [trixPosVector1; trixPosVector2; trixPosVector3; trixPosVector4; trixPosVector5; trixPosVector6; triyPosVector7];
    elseif setSize(i) == 8
        triyPosVector1 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(1);
        trixPosVector1 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(1);
        triyPosVector2 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(2);
        trixPosVector2 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(2);
        triyPosVector3 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(3);
        trixPosVector3 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(3);
        triyPosVector4 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(4);
        trixPosVector4 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(4);
        triyPosVector5 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(5);
        trixPosVector5 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(5);
        triyPosVector6 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(6);
        trixPosVector6 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(6);
        triyPosVector7 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(7);
        trixPosVector7 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(7);
        triyPosVector8 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(8);
        trixPosVector8 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(8);
        triyPosVector = [triyPosVector1; triyPosVector2; triyPosVector3; triyPosVector4; triyPosVector5; triyPosVector6; triyPosVector7; triyPosVector8];
        trixPosVector = [trixPosVector1; trixPosVector2; trixPosVector3; trixPosVector4; trixPosVector5; trixPosVector6; triyPosVector7; triyPosVector8];

    elseif setSize(i) == 9
        triyPosVector1 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(1);
        trixPosVector1 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(1);
        triyPosVector2 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(2);
        trixPosVector2 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(2);
        triyPosVector3 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(3);
        trixPosVector3 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(3);
        triyPosVector4 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(4);
        trixPosVector4 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(4);
        triyPosVector5 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(5);
        trixPosVector5 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(5);
        triyPosVector6 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(6);
        trixPosVector6 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(6);
        triyPosVector7 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(7);
        trixPosVector7 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(7);
        triyPosVector8 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(8);
        trixPosVector8 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(8);
        triyPosVector9 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(9);
        trixPosVector9 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(9);
        triyPosVector = [triyPosVector1; triyPosVector2; triyPosVector3; triyPosVector4; triyPosVector5; triyPosVector6; triyPosVector7; triyPosVector8; triyPosVector9];
        trixPosVector = [trixPosVector1; trixPosVector2; trixPosVector3; trixPosVector4; trixPosVector5; trixPosVector6; triyPosVector7; triyPosVector8; triyPosVector9];

    elseif setSize(i) == 10
        triyPosVector1 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(1);
        trixPosVector1 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(1);
        triyPosVector2 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(2);
        trixPosVector2 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(2);
        triyPosVector3 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(3);
        trixPosVector3 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(3);
        triyPosVector4 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(4);
        trixPosVector4 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(4);
        triyPosVector5 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(5);
        trixPosVector5 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(5);
        triyPosVector6 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(6);
        trixPosVector6 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(6);
        triyPosVector7 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(7);
        trixPosVector7 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(7);
        triyPosVector8 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(8);
        trixPosVector8 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(8);
        triyPosVector9 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(9);
        trixPosVector9 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(9);
        triyPosVector10 = sin(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + yy(10);
        trixPosVector10 = cos(anglesRadtri) .* expinfo.radi2 + xx(10);
        triyPosVector = [triyPosVector1; triyPosVector2; triyPosVector3; triyPosVector4; triyPosVector5; triyPosVector6; triyPosVector7; triyPosVector8; triyPosVector9; triyPosVector10];
        trixPosVector = [trixPosVector1; trixPosVector2; trixPosVector3; trixPosVector4; trixPosVector5; trixPosVector6; triyPosVector7; triyPosVector8; triyPosVector9; triyPosVector10];

    end

%then I draw the stimuli on the screen. 

    for pos = 1:setSize(i)  % Drawing the stimuli

            % Draw a triangle
            Screen('FillPoly', expinfo.w, expinfo.colors(trial(i).memoryColors(pos), :), [trixPosVector(pos, :); triyPosVector(pos, :)]', 2);


    end
```

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without knowing what all of your positioning variables have been set to. Could you post a more complete example that contains enough information to display the triangles?

Comment: Hi DMR, thanks for writing! I updated my question with the full information now. Would be nice to hear what you think! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The points for polygons 7 - 10 are currently being drawn to the screen as lines. If you change 'FillPoly' to 'FramePoly' you can see where they are located. The FillPoly command doesn't show them because as a straight line there is no region to fill. I haven't read through all of the geometry logic you are using to place the triangles, but it seems that there is a problem with the algorithm for how triangles 7 - 10 are determined.

Comment: Hello DMR, thanks so much for pointing that out! Trying the FramePoly showed what the function was drawing - it was as trivial as a copy-paste mistake. The coordinates were displaced - x and y were not in the right order. Thanks for your help, really appreciate it!